# How to get the latest ID from different class in Django

Tags: python, django

I saw all the conversations about this issue, but I can't solve it. I am new in this Python-Django programming so if anyone can help me? :)

This is my views.py:

```
class HistoryProjectCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'layout/create_proj_history.html'
    model = ProjectHistory
    project = Project.objects.latest('id')
    user = User.id

    fields = ['user', 'project', 'user_start_date']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('git_project:index')
```

Var project has to return latest project ID from database, and I have to use it ID in my html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="user"></label>
    <input id="user" type="text" name="user" value="{{ user.id }}" ><br>
    <label for="project">Project title: </label>

    <input id="project" type="text" name="project" value="{{ project.id }}" ><br>

<!--Here - "project.id" I need latest project ID-->

    <label for="user_start_date">Start date: </label>
    <input id="user_start_date" type="date" name="user_start_date" value="{{ projectHistory.user_start_date }}" ><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am not sure if `project = Project.objects.latest('id')` is correct statement for getting the latest ID from Project table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last Id of project, you need to order by id, and use `last()` function available on queryset

```
project = Project.objects.order_by('id').last()
```

[Order_by doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

[Last function doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#last)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it didn't pass the latest id in my HTML form. Can You help me with this? :)

Comment: what do you obtain ? Your variable 'project' in your context, contains the good object ?

Comment: This returns me the first project ID from database (from table Project). I also tried to order_by('-id') but nothing changed. It always returns the first project id.

Comment: Wow, you are telling me that : order_by('id').last() and order_by('-id').last() returns the same id ? That's weird. Can you show me what Project.objects.order_by('id') and Project.objects.order_by('-id') returns ?

Comment: Yes. I know that is weird, but I don't know why its happened. It returned me proj_title from database (I specified it in .html) and proj_title for Project.objects.order_by('id') and for Project.objects.order_by('-id') is "Django projekat". I don't know how to put prt cs in comment box, sorry! :)

Comment: Becarefull, project title can be the same for two different project object. Can you display `project.id` for the two differents request. I'm sure `id`, will be different.

Comment: I tried it, but the output is the same. Maybe there is a mistake in my model. In model.py I have classes Project and ProjectHistory and in ProjectHistory I tried to return last project ID because I have to fill in ProjectHistory table, but i want, the field project_title be filled in with last project from Project table. If you need more details, I will update my Question with model.py, and thanks one more time for Your help!

Comment: Yes, detail your question and add your model.py :) It's unclear for me

Comment: You were right! Your answer was correct, but I was make mistake with object. Thanks for Your help, and sorry for late answering. :)